# Binding a map of classes to instances inside guice module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection

I am currently trying to add the entries of a map consisting of `Map<? extends CustomModule, CustomModule>` (from an additional, custom module system) as bindings within a guice module.

My code so far looks like this:

```
manager.getRegistry().forEach(new BiConsumer<Class<? extends CustomModule>, ModuleRegistry.Entry>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Class<? extends CustomModule> moduleClass, ModuleRegistry.Entry entry) {
        bind(moduleClass).to(entry.getModule()); // getModule() returns the instance which implements moduleClass
    }
});
```

Guice sadly needs the direct class instead of a wildcard ("? extends").
Since I already got the "bindings", is there another way to add them to the injector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying various other possible ways, I finally found one that works.
Since the original problem was that Guice required a "capture" of something (in this case "capture of ? extends Module instance", basically means something that is an instance of something that is a module) and failed, I had to cast my already known module class to its raw type, like this:

```
final Class moduleClass = (Class) aClass;
final Binding binding = injector.getExistingBinding(Key.get(moduleClass));
if (binding == null) {
    bind(moduleClass).toInstance(entry.getModule());
}
```

I also had to add a null check in my case, but it also includes the way how to cast your unknown class to guice's "Key" helper.